# Как на Си через winapi переместить окно в другое место на экране?

Tags: c, winapi

Как на Си через winapi переместить окно в другое место на экране?

Comment: Пробовали сперва открывать справочник? [MSDN: SetWindowPos function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо. Оно движется! :)

Comment: @AlexKrass: Тогда, возможно, имеет смысл превратить в ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала пробуйте найти подходящее решение в справочнике MSDN, в большинстве случаев Вы найдете подходящую функцию или описание там.

[Раздел MSDN посвященный Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx)

Интересующая Вас функция [User Input and Messaging > Windows and Messages > Windows > Window Functions > SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью функции SetWindowPos().